# Typescript - Transform imports for npm distribution

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, npm-publish

I am working on an NPM package written in Typescript, and I am having trouble wrapping my head around module resolution when compiling the library to publish.

Throughout the project, I have been using non-relative imports to avoid the annoyance of `../../../`. However, I read in the typescript documentation that relative imports should be used within a project.

> A relative import is resolved relative to the importing file and cannot resolve to an ambient module declaration. You should use relative imports for your own modules that are guaranteed to maintain their relative location at runtime.
>
> A non-relative import can be resolved relative to baseUrl, or through path mapping, which we’ll cover below. They can also resolve to ambient module declarations. Use non-relative paths when importing any of your external dependencies.

I would like to not have to sacrifice the nice, neat imports in favor of relative imports, but I am not sure how to set up the compiler settings in order to get this to work. When running tests, I specify `NODE_PATH` in order to resolve the modules, but this isn't working for post-compilation.

I would like to be able to write files using non-relative imports, but have them transformed in some way so that the `dist/` files can resolve the imports.

The project is hosted on github [here](https://github.com/matthewwolfe/active-record-js).

The relevant issue is that I end up with an `index.d.ts` file in my `dist/` folder that looks like this:

```
import { Emitter } from 'emitter';
import { Schema } from 'migrations';
import { Model, model, relation } from 'model';
import { Builder } from 'query';

export { Builder, Emitter, Model, model, relation, Schema };
```

But all the modules have errors that the module cannot be resolved. How can I keep these imports in their current form, but transform them in some way when building so that when I publish the npm package, the modules can be correctly resolved.

Comment: Have you considered bundling the npm package only with the compiled files? A typescript module can be distributed just as a js file + an accompanying d.ts file. Couldn't you just compile the thing before shipping to npm?

Comment: @A.Chiesa When setting module to ```commonjs```, you can only specify an output directory, but not an output file.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the advice in the official Typescript docs:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Basically, the suggestion is to build your library just before publishing to npm. You will have two files, in output; let's call them `main.js` and `main.d.ts`.

The critical point, here, is that by tsc-ing your source files you resolve the dependencies before npm is involved at all, so you can keep your references as you wish.

In your `package.json`, include two lines (or change them accordingly, if you have them already):

```
{
    ...
    "main": "./lib/main.js",
    "types": "./lib/main.d.ts"
    ...
}
```

In this way, any consuming project doesn't need to know about the internals of your library: they can just use the compiled output, referencing the generated typings file.

Comment: The main issue with that is if I set the module to ```commonjs```, I cannot compile to a single file. And all of the documentation and tutorials I see have been based on a single file, which is why I am a little stuck.